# Post A Review from the front page of website

Tags: wordpress, web, frontend

I am creating a Review site where products, services etc are written about and rated. Just like yelp. I'm building it with wordpress and you can only post reviews from the admin back-end.

Now my question is this:

How can I allow users to post a review from the front-end? This website (http://www.reviewnaija.com/post-a-review/) has it the exact way I want mine to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution for your problem would be to use the [Advanced Custom Fields](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) plugin and its [acf_form](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf_form/). Learn [how to create a new post (review in your case) using acf_form](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/using-acf_form-to-create-a-new-post/).

Comment: looks promising. Let me try it out and give a feedback. Thanks